# How to know the line number corresponding to a buffer position?

Tags: emacs, buffer

When Emacs reports error it always show code with a buffer position, with which it is quite unconvenient to find out where the exact words locate.

It there any way to know the exact line number of the buffer position?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

- <kbd>C-x =</kbd> Bound to `what-cursor-position`; shows the current position.
- <kbd>C-x l</kbd> Bound to `count-lines-page`; shows how many lines are before and after point on page, and total number of lines on page (where "page" spans lines between two page-break symbols `^L`).
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> Bound to `what-line`; shows line number of current line (and narrowed line number of point, if applicable).

But I think what you want is

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `goto-char` <kbd>RET</kbd> `<pos>`

which lets you go to position `<pos>` in the current buffer.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer.  I just edited to clarify the distinction between the command and the explanation of it; hope that's OK.

Comment: A good way to access the buffer line number at a given position *programmatically* is `(line-number-at-pos <pos>)`.

Comment: I would *love* a way to enable showing what-cursor-position in the mode line. Any suggestions? All I currently see is the line:column display.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need Goto line: M-g g

The exact line number of the buffer position is shown in the status line of your Emacs buffer.

Comment: Don't know why this is rated '-1', it is correct. One should find the current line number in the mode-line, it the number after the `L` and before the major mode name. 'M-g g' is available only since emacs 22.1.

Comment: I'm not downvoting since it's correct, but it fails to answer the question that was asked.

Comment: My apologies, I was confused by "buffer position". This emacs phraseology is a bit elusive.

To my answer, I would also add the following emacs bindings:
M-g n           next-error
M-g p           previous-error
One could browse through errors without telling line numbers.